# get total sum of minutes between 2 fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

im trying to get the total minutes from this 2 fields but i keep getting the 60 minutes results but wont show more even when there is few hours in between.

sample
01:59    04:59   getting result 60 minutes
01:59    04:59   wanted result 299 minutes

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ($('#duration').val() === '') {
        updateDuration($('#start_time').val(), $('#end_time').val());
    }

    $('#start_time').on('change keyup', function () {
        updateDuration($('#start_time').val(), $('#end_time').val());
    });

    $('#end_time').on('change keyup', function () {
        updateDuration($('#start_time').val(), $('#end_time').val());
    });

    function updateDuration(startTime, endTime) {
        var ms = moment(endTime, ' HH:mm:ss').diff(moment(startTime, 'HH:mm:ss')),
            dt = moment.duration(ms),
            h = Math.floor(dt.asHours()),
            m = moment.utc(ms).format('mm');

        $('#duration').val('' + m + ' minutes');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.5.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<p>
    <label for="start_time">Start Time</label>
    <br>
    <input id="start_time" name="start_time" type="text" value="00:00">
</p>
<p>
    <label for="end_time">End Time</label>
    <br>
    <input id="end_time" name="end_time" type="text" value="15:53">
</p>
<p>
    <label for="duration">Duration</label>
    <br>
    <input id="duration" name="duration" type="text">
</p>
```

Comment: I am realizing after posting an answer that your expected results didn't make sense to me. How do you get 66 minutes from 23:59 01:59?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it without moment. Just convert everything to seconds and subtract. If the endtime is less than the start time, we add 24 hours to the end.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {


  $('#start_time, #end_time').on('keyup', function() {
    updateDuration($('#start_time').val(), $('#end_time').val());
  });

  $('#start_time').trigger('keyup')

});

const getSeconds = t => t.split(":").reduce((b, a, i) => b + (+a * (i === 0 ? 60 : 1)),0);

function updateDuration(startTime, endTime) {
  let start = getSeconds(startTime),
    end = getSeconds(endTime)
  if (end < start) end += (24 * 60 )
  let result = end - start
  let m = Math.floor(result/60), s = Math.floor((result%60))
  $('#duration').val(`${m} minutes, ${s} seconds`);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.5.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<p>
  <label for="start_time">Start Time</label>
  <br>
  <input id="start_time" name="start_time" type="text" value="23:59">
</p>
<p>
  <label for="end_time">End Time</label>
  <br>
  <input id="end_time" name="end_time" type="text" value="15:53">
</p>
<p>
  <label for="duration">Duration</label>
  <br>
  <input id="duration" name="duration" type="text">
</p>
```